# Trouble with creating a trigger to print a statement after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am working on a project where I need to create a trigger that prints a statement each time an insert is performed on a table called enrolled.
This trigger is expected to print the **faculty name, meeting location, time, student name** after an insert is performed but when I run this trigger, it completes but after an insert is performed on the enrolled table, it does not print any information but the insert does complete and populates the table with the values. this is the test code I created below, along with the tables required to pull each value and a sample insert statement. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    USE test
GO
CREATE TRIGGER afterinsertprint on test.dbo.enrolled
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

  DECLARE @studentname VARCHAR(30), @meetat varchar(30), @facultyname VARCHAR (30), @location NVARCHAR(10), @studentnumber int, @coursename NVARCHAR(12)

  SELECT @studentnumber = snum, @coursename = cname FROM INSERTED;

  SET @studentname = (SELECT sname from test.dbo.student WHERE snum = @studentnumber)

  SELECT @facultyname = FNAME from test.dbo.faculty f join test.dbo.student s ON s.DEPT_ID = f.DEPT_ID where s.snum in 
  (SELECT snum FROM test.dbo.enrolled WHERE snum =  @studentnumber and CNAME = @coursename);

  SELECT @meetat = meets_at, @location = room FROM test.dbo.class WHERE cname IN (SELECT cname FROM test.dbo.enrolled 
  WHERE snum = @studentnumber and cname = @coursename);

  IF (@studentnumber IS NOT NULL and @coursename IS NOT NULL)

  BEGIN

  PRINT (@studentname +  @facultyname + @meetat + @location)

  END;
  END;
```

---

Below are the DML/DLL for table creation/insert

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.STUDENT
     (snum      int,
      sname     nvarchar(12),
      MAJOR     nvarchar(12),
      DEPT_ID   int,
      slevel    nvarchar(12),
      AGE       int,
      CONSTRAINT STUDENT_SNUM_pk PRIMARY KEY (SNUM));
--
CREATE TABLE dbo.CLASS
     (CNAME     nvarchar(12),
      MEETS_AT  time,
      ROOM      nvarchar(10),
      FID       int,
      CONSTRAINT CLASS_CNAME_pk PRIMARY KEY (CNAME));
--
 
CREATE TABLE dbo.ENROLLED
   (SNUM        int,
   CNAME        nvarchar(12));
--
CREATE TABLE dbo.FACULTY
     (FID       int,
     FNAME      nvarchar(40),
      DEPT_ID   int,
      CONSTRAINT FACULTY_FID_pk PRIMARY KEY (FID));
--
CREATE TABLE dbo.DEPARTMENT
      (DEPTid   int,
       DNAME    nvarchar(100),
       LOCATION nvarchar(100),
       
       CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_DEPTID_pk PRIMARY KEY (DEPTID));

insert into dbo.STUDENT values (1234,'T.Banks','ME',3,'SR',19);

insert into dbo.DEPARTMENT values (1,'Computer Sciences','West Lafayette');

insert into dbo.FACULTY values (107,'Y.Walton',1);

insert into dbo.CLASS values ('ENG400',cast('08:30' as time),'U003',107);

insert into dbo.ENROLLED values (1234,'ENG400');
```

Comment: Your trigger is fundamentally broken... you assume that `inserted` will only contain a single row... whereas it can contain 0-N. You need to use something like the cursor from you previous question - which is probably why you have been asked those questions in that order. Join your tables, using `Inserted` and then loop through the rows printing them.

Comment: Aside: Note that if any variable in `@studentname + @facultyname + @meetat + @location` is `NULL` then the result will be `NULL`. Have a look at [`concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if you want `NULL` strings to be treated as empty strings (`''`).

Comment: Lastly, triggers should NEVER attempt to return information in a production system. For a simple school  tsql-based project, printing might be acceptable. In addition, develop GOOD habits. Your tsql code should not be using 3 part names (e.g., test.dbo.enrolled). Your statements should be written using 2 part names (with aliases) only - especially in compiled code (or code that is otherwise stored within a specific database).